# DevExpress GridView FocusedRowHandle Does not update on right click

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, right-click

I have a DevExpress datagridview that list a number of jobs that our employees must do some work on. In practice, a job(row) is right clicked, and a menuItem to launch a different part of the program is selected. The information that is filled into the next part of the program comes from the FocusedRowHandle.

```
Dim someString as String = gvMyGV.GetRowCellValue(gvMyGV.FocusedRowHandle, "ColumnHeader")
```

Now, if the employee left clicks the row to select it, and then right clicks -> MenuItem to launch the next step, all is well. But if they right click any other row that is not already highlighted, the FocusRowHandle does not update to the newly clicked row until after the next stage is launched, causing it to load the information for the job that was selceted before they performed the right click.

The DevEx selected row highlighting visually updates (row turns yellow), but the FocusedRowHandle Value sticks until after the Context Menu closes.

I need the RowHandle to update on the right click, before the ContextMenu loads.

SOLUTION FOUND:

```
 Private Sub gvMyGV_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles gvMyGV.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim hitInfo As GridHitInfo = gvMyGV.CalcHitInfo(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        gvStatus.FocusedRowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that is not unique to your control.  LClick sets the active/focused item, RClick does not.  You'll have to account for that in the RCLick or MouseDown event

Comment: But it does after the context menu closes. As in, I can right click a row to open the context menu, and then left click an empty area of the GridControl, and the selection updates correctly. So something has to be getting the value from somewhere.

Comment: After the CM closes, 2-3 *other* events and untold lines of code have run to do stuff.  RClick *alone* does not make a control active.  Even opening an empty CM over something like a ListBox will not change the focus or select that item.

Comment: I think my first comment came across as argumentative, which was not my intention. Do you know what those other few events are so that I could try to capture them and extract the data that I need?  Since it updates after it closes, I assume that the data is in there somewhere.

Comment: I have something like what you describe for a ListView CM.  In the mousedown event, get the mouse XY, convert to item/row reference to get relevant info before the menu opens.  The normal DGV has HitTest related methods for this; yours may also.  *Generally* doing something like this in the CM Opening event is too late if the menu needs to use some dynamic info from the control.item like a DGV.Row

Comment: ....naturally you can also set the selected row when you do that, *but* that may trigger events you do not want to happen while the menu is open/opening

Comment: Got it working with the HitTest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is they way it has always been. Here is some code I pulled from an app I needed this fixed in but it was using DevExpress 8, but it should be the same.

```
Private Sub GridView2_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles GridView2.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim view As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
            If view Is Nothing Then Return
            ' obtaining hit info
            Dim hitInfo As GridHitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
            ' switching focus
            view.FocusedRowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, figured this out just before you posted. Appreciate the answer.